# killall -i[id] init command working?

Tags: linux, shell, kill, init

when I use killall -1 init command in terminal it will give me an error that " init(1): Operation not permitted "

The script

```
for i in `seq 1 100`;
do
killall -$i init
done
```

But the above script will kill some process. Can any one guide me what actually this command do and why it will restart my system when I run this script ?

After several runs of the script my system became halt, i want to know that reason ?

i am not using super user permission.

Comment: No, `the above script will kill some process` is not a good explanation of what happens. init will ignore many signals, but there are some it catches. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85364/how-can-i-check-what-signals-a-process-is-listening-to). And then it would be interesting to know which of your machinegun-series of signals made init shut down the computer. One good candidate is SIGPWR - see `man 8 init`.

Comment: actually i have an assignment to crash the kernel from user mode, this script is working in that scenario. But i want to know how it is working ?

Comment: can you guide me what that script is doing ? why and how this script crash my system ?

Comment: The script is equivalent to `killall -1 init ; killall -2 init ; killall -3 init` and and so on, up to `killall -100 init`, ie it sends signals 1 to 100 to all processes with the name init. One (or more) of these signals **shuts down** the computer, I honestly don't think it will actually crash the computer. To find out which signals initiates the shutdown, you can execute them one by one and see what happens. Background on what's going on can be found in the question I linked to.